# FFMPEG corrupting audio data when trying to edit metadata

Tags: powershell, audio, ffmpeg, metadata

I'm trying to use FFMPEG to edit some metadata in Powershell. My problem is that FFMPEG simply outputs an audio file with the correct metadata, but the audio does not play. The length of the track is reduced to a fraction of a second. Here is the command I'm using in Powershell:

```
& $ffmpeg -y -i $flac.fullname -c copy -metadata track="$tracknumber" $flac.fullname
```

Previously, I tried having `-map 0:0` in there too, but it didn't make a difference. Thanks for any help.

Edit: I'm not sure if this is intentional behavior or not, but if I change the output path to be a new destination (rather than saving over the old destination) it does work correctly. So as a workaround, I'm just using a temp folder as an output then moving the files back to where I want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg does NOT do in-place editing. Destination has to be a new file.

```
ffmpeg -y -i file.flac -c copy -metadata track="$tracknumber" newfile.flac
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after some more research. One of the first examples I saw of metadata editing incorrectly had input and output identical so I assumed from the start that it was possible. I edited the OP to reflect this, but thank you for your answer!